# How can I edit nested objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, put

Current I am able to edit objects that are not nested. I want to edit both parent and nested object properties. How can I do this using mongoose.

**Edit route:-**

```
router.put('/editUser/:userId', checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.userData.role2 === 'superadmin') {
    const id  = req.params.userId;
    const newUserData  = req.body;
    Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {$set: newUserData}, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
                if (err) return res.send(err.message);
                if (doc) return res.send(doc);

            })
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(["Not authorized. Only super admin can update details."]);
    }       
});
```

**Controller:-**

```
module.exports.register = (req, res, next) =>{  

    var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.address = req.body.address;
    admin.admins = {
                    firstName : req.body.firstName, 
                    lastName : req.body.lastName,
                    phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber,
    };
```

I have **response json** like this :-

```
{
  "admins": {
            "firstName": "ABC",
            "lastName": "FF",
            "phoneNumber": "855599"
   },
  "_id": "5d008f5a287805414247bd33",
  "companyName": "ABC",
  "address" : "UAE"
  "__v": 0
}
```

*I can edit `companyName` and `address` . How can I edit nested object properties also ?? What changes do I have to make in edit route ?*

**EDIT Added schema**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },
    address :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Address can't be empty."
                },
    admins:     {
                firstName : {
                            type: String,
                            required: "First name can't be empty."
                            },
                lastName : {
                            type: String,
                            required: "Last name can't be empty."
                            },  
                phoneNumber :{
                            type: String,
                            required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                            }
    }           
});
mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
```

And in Postman if I want to edit `phoneNumber` simply I am passing

url:- `localhost:3000/api/editUser/{id}` with body `"{phoneNumber": "0000000"}`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `async/await` to optimize your code :

```
router.put('/editUser/:userId', checkAuth, async function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.userData.role2 === 'superadmin') {
    const id  = req.params.userId;
    const newUserData  = req.body;
    let newData = await Admin.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
    newData['admins'].firstName = 'new First Name'
    newData['admins'].lastName = 'new Last Name'
    newData['admins'].phoneNumber = 'new Phone Number'
    await newData.save();
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(["Not authorized. Only super admin can update details."]);
    }       
});
```

**UPDATE FIX SCHEMA AND ROUTER**
Your `Admin Shema` should be :

```
let adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },
    address :   {
                type: String,
                },
    admins:     {
                type : new Schema({
                firstName : {
                            type: String,
                            required: true
                            },
                lastName : {
                            type: String,
                            required: true
                            },  
                phoneNumber :{
                            type: String,
                            required: true
                            }
                    })
                    }     
});
mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
```

Goodluck.

Comment: But I am not hardcoding it. How will I mention it in route ? can you edit my route ?

Comment: When I am testing it on POSTMAN it is not working , although I don't want this approach. You are hard coding the edit data. I want to test through input method. And in some point if the list of the keys of nested structure increases , it will create problem in hard coding.

Comment: Added in  EDIT in my question

Comment: Check new update answer. You should use `findOne` and define scheme carefully.Maybe remove `checkAtuh` middleware for testing.

Comment: Please try again with new schema

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194858/discussion-between-noobcoder-and-le-quang).